# Display a date field in the attribute table window as yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: qgis, date

At 3.28.6, I have a GeoPackage table with a date field which always displays in the attribute table window as M/d/yyyy.  I would like it to display as the ISO 8601 standard yyyy-MM-dd.

Using the Field Calculator I try `format_date("date_field", 'yyyy-MM-dd')`. No error occurs, but the result still displays M/d/yyyy.

How do I display a date field in the attribute table window as yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: There may be a difference between 'yyyy' and 'YYYY' in formatting. There's certainly a differences between '%y' and '%Y' and '%m' and '%M'  in `strftime`.  Have you tried using 'YYYY-MM-DD'?

Comment: Alas, neither YYYY or DD are recognized by the Field Calculator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use the Field Calculator. If you go to Layer Properties -> Attributes Form, you can set the **Widget Type** to **Date/Time** and the **Field Format** to yyyy-MM-dd. See screenshot:

[image]

Attribute table below:

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer!  But it requires modifying each and every qgz file, which got me rethinking my OP... in retrospect I was thinking along the lines of being able to customize a program-level QGIS setting, so that date or datetime fields *always* displayed in the desired format, without having to modify every project.  It also seems  odd that the default QGIS date format is M/d/yyyy rather than the ISO 8601 standard of yyyy-MM-dd.  I may post a new question along these lines if nothing appears here in the next few days.

Comment: Pretty sure QGIS default date format is taken from the System. For example, mine is d/MM/yyyy rather than M/d/yyyy (eg 31/12/2022). But if you want to ask your followup, ask it as a new question - the comments are just for clarifications (and it will help other people who might have the same question!).